# pycharm console wrong behavior on help(class_name)

Tags: pycharm

When I type in pycharm console help(class_name), or help(module_name) the console get's stuck.

In iPython when one types in help(class_name) one just keep pressing space bar to read more, or Q to exit help.

When I try this in Pycharm Console nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Isn't it scrollable? mine is

Comment: @NipunSampath sadly it isn't.  I think in local console may work? unsure since i only use it in remote console.  apparently it's a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/PY-26804

Comment: yeah, I tried on the local console. It was scrollable there